# How to hide mouse cursor using JOGL2?

Tags: java, jogl, mouse-cursor

I'm using JOGL2 and the NativeWindow APIs to write an app in Java. How can I  hide the mouse cursor?

[EDIT]
I'm not using JFrame to create a window but rather GLWindow from JOGL. GLWindow does not have a setCursor method. Is this still possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you (thekidder) say `GLWindow` does not have that capability so I would use `GLCanvas` inside a `Frame` (or `JFrame`) like this (like AlexR wrote):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    // create the cursor
    Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image i = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Cursor noCursor = t.createCustomCursor(i, new Point(0, 0), "none"); 

    // try it with a normal frame
    Frame f = new Frame();

    // create the GLCanvas and add it to the frame
    GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();
    frame.add(canvas);

    f.setCursor(noCursor);
    f.setSize(400, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: NP, so you cannot use the solution? You have to use the `GLWindow`?

Comment: I can do that, I just wanted to be sure of my options ;)

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate, please see my answer for a NEWT solution.

Answer (score 2):

This has since been implemented in JOGL2 using NEWT (a GLWindow object).  See https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=409 (referenced in thekidder's answer).

You can do it like so:

```
glWindow.setPointerVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If mouse is in the area of application window you can set any image as a custom cursor. Use transparent image 1x1 pixel. I used it - works fine. It is regular API, no JOGL, no native code.

Answer (score 0):

After some further searching it appears that this is not implemented for NEWT windows in JOGL2 yet. There is an enhancement request filed on JOGL's bugzilla: http://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=409

Answer (score 0):

At the current time with NEWT GLWindow:

```
window = GLWindow.create(caps);
```

...

```
window.requestFocus();
window.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // i think, be on top is good than mouse is jailed
window.setUndecorated(true); // remove window borders (if u want)
window.setPointerVisible(false); // hide cursor
window.confinePointer(true); // jail inside (cursor will be limited to window borders)
```